# Get metadata from linkedin Sales Navigator

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, puppeteer

Trying to get the network response(only metadata) from linked Sales Navigator Search by using the [code] selector.

[image]

I can take this element or text by using an absolute path `$x("/html/body/code[9]")[0].innerHTML`
but I want to be more generic in case this path is changed, by contains text ex "metadata"

is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to make the simplest one.

```
const metadatas = await page.evaluate ( () => {

    let metadatas = []

    document.querySelectorAll('body > code[style="display: none"]').forEach(code => {
        if ( code.innerText.search('{"metadata":"') > -1 && code.innerText.search('{"metadata":"') < 10 ) {
            metadatas.push (code.innerText)
        }
    })

    return (metadatas)

})

metadatas.forEach( metadata => console.log ( JSON.parse(metadata) ) )
```

If you're sure that the `$("code")[8].innerHTML` will contain the metadata, the you can write the code like this.

```
const metadatas = await page.evaluate ( () => {

    let metadatas = []

    document.querySelectorAll('body > code[style="display: none"]:nth-of-type(9)').forEach(code => {
        metadatas.push (code.innerText)
    })

    return (metadatas)

})

metadatas.forEach( metadata => console.log ( JSON.parse(metadata) ) )
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. > - 1 ... < 10 doesn't take anything. Removing these will take all the JSON text from tag code. How do I only take the content contained in the metadata '$("code")[8].innerHTML'.

Comment: I've edit my answer above as you like, so if it's works, please select this as the right answer.